# ASP.NET MVC Razor Dynamic menu <li class='current'>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have an HTML Menu that I render as a `PartialView` in my Shared `Layout.cshtml` and has the following structure:

I call the menu in my `Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
 @Html.Action("LeftMenu", "Common", new { context = ViewContext})
```

This is the left menu structure:

```
<li class='current'>
   <a class='current' href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
   <span class="badge pull-right">17</span>
   <i class="icon-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="@Url.Action("Absence","Incident")" class="is-dropdown-menu">
   <span class="badge pull-right"></span>
   <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Absence List
   </a>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="@Url.Action("AbsenceList","Incident")">
         <i class="icon-random"></i>
         Notice List
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="@Url.Action("NewAbsence","Incident")">
         <i class="icon-bullseye"></i>
         New Notice
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

And I want to make my links dynamic to depending on the current View I can activate the `<li>` element by assigning the `class='current'` and also to the `<a href>` element.

I saw that I can do that using a HTML Helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string text,
        string action, 
        string controller
    )
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
```

But the above code I don't think It will help me create the exact `<li>` structure that my menu requires in order to look nice.

[image]

If I Inspect (google chrome) my active menu element what I get is this:

[image]

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: The helper you have shown can easily be modified to include the `<span>` and `<i>` elements you want (and change the class name from "active" to "current")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically do something like the following:

```
@{ string url; }
<ul>
    @{ url = Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController"); }
    <li>
        <a class="@(url == Request.Url.AbsolutePath ? "current" : string.Empty)" href="@url">
            Some Action
        </a>
    </li>

    @{ url = Url.Action("SomeOtherAction", "SomeOtherController"); }
    <li>
        <a class="@(url == Request.Url.AbsolutePath ? "current" : string.Empty)" href="@url">
            Some Other Action
        </a>
    </li>

    ...
```

In other words, in each case, you compare the URL for the link with the currently requested URL and render the class when it matches.

Answer (score 2):

The helper can be modified to generate the output your seeking

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string action, string controller, string num, string icon)
{
    var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
    var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    bool isCurrent = string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    string url = urlHelper.Action(action, controller);
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.AddCssClass("badge pull-right");
    span.InnerHtml = num;
    html.Append(span);
    TagBuilder i = new TagBuilder("i");
    i.AddCssClass(icon);
    html.Append(i);
    span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.InnerHtml = text;
    html.Append(span);
    TagBuilder a = new TagBuilder("a");
    a.MergeAttribute("href", url);
    if (isCurrent)
    {
        a.AddCssClass("current");
    }
    a.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li");
    if (isCurrent)
    {
        li.AddCssClass("current");
    }
    li.InnerHtml = a.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
}
```

and use it in the view as

```
@Html.MenuItem("Dashboard", "Index", "Home", "17", "icon-dashboard")
```